# Refined -dV termination method for charging NiMH batteries

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, nimh

In a [radio control forum](https://www.rcuniverse.com/forum/batteries-chargers-84/11406450-how-charge-nimh-batteries-2.html?ispreloading=1) I have read the following statement:

> The minus delta V bump that is indicative of end-of-charge is much
> less pronounced in NiMH than NiCad, and it is very temperature
> dependent. To make matters worse, new NiMH batteries can exhibit bumps
> in the curve early in the cycle, particularly when cold. Also, NiMH
> are sensitive to damage on overcharge when the charge rate is over
> C/10. Since the delta V bump is not always easy to see, slight
> overcharge is probable. For this reason PowerStream does not recommend
> using simple minus delta V as a termination criterion for nickel metal
> hydride batteries. **However, modern algorithms have been developed to
> enable accurate charging without using a thermistor. These chargers
> are similar to the -delta V chargers, but have special measurement
> techniques to detect a full charge, usually involving some kind of
> pulse cycle where the voltage is measured during the pulse and between
> pulses.** For multicell packs, if the cells are not all at the same
> state of charge, and if they are not balanced in capacity, the cells
> may fill up one at a time, bluring out the end-of-charge signal. In
> order to balance the cells it may take several charge-discharge
> cycles. Luckily, NiMH does not mind being overcharged at C/10 or less,
> which allows the charger to balance the cells during the trickle
> charge.

(Bold mine)

No I am looking for more detailed information about those "special measurement techniques" of modern chargers. Do you have some references? What is the technical term for this refined -dV termination method?

I have looked the specs of several available hobby charges. If at all it is only said that they use simple -dV as termination method (if someone knows a specific hobby charger using the refined method above, it would be nice if you could post a link in a comment, but that's not the main question).